# Detect passport size photo from image using emgu or Aforge.net in c#

Tags: image-processing, emgucv, aforge

I have tried face detection using emgu in c#. What i am trying to do is detect face from image and crop it and save as a seperate image.

Right now after detecting the face i expand the rectangle to certain size so that it covers the full passport size photo. But this solution will not work for images of different sizes.

Please guide me how to detect passport size photo from image. I know of two image processing libraries emgu (open CV) and Aforge.net

Comment: Can you upload some example images?

Comment: you may probably want to adjust the resolution/aspect ratio before performing your operations on the image.